# Is there a way to hook or call a custom woocomerce template that is not part of the default templates of woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, templates

So I'm currently using Woocommerce and managed to figure how to override templates based on the documentation. Now I have a problem, so i managed to override a specific template let's say `upsell.php`. Right now I need to create another `upsell.php` template that provides a different layout. Lets just call it `up-sell-alternate.php`

Now my question is it possible to create a hook and fetch that custom template even though it is not part of the woocomerce templates.

I need to reuse various parts of woocommerce templates and provide a different layouts for each of them. I cannot to find something that fits my question on the documentation of woocommerce

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using the good ol' `get_template_part( string $slug, string $name = null, array $args = array()` function, which is a native WP function. Especially now as it supports the third parameter for passing data to the template file (since WP 5.5).

Create a function (in your (child) theme functions.php file) that wraps around some `get_template_part()` call and hook it onto suitable action that WooCommerce provides.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

**EDIT 30.8.2020**

You could for example have the following structure in your (child) theme directory,

```
/my-child-theme
--/parts
----/my-template-part.php
----/my-template-part-alt.php
```

To use the custom template parts, you could do the following in your `functions.php` file.

```
add_action( 'some_woocommerce_template_action', 'my_fancy_template_part' );
function my_fancy_template_part() {
    // pass data to the template part in an array
    $args = array(
        'key_1' => 'foo',
        'key_2' => 'bar',
    );
    get_template_part( '/parts/my-template-part', null, $args );
}

add_action( 'some_other_woocommerce_template_action', 'my_fancy_template_part_alternative' );
function my_fancy_template_part_alternative() {
    // get a "named" part with shared prefix
    get_template_part( '/parts/my-template-part', 'alt' );
}
```

If you passed $args as the third parameter to `get_template_part()`, you can the access them in your template part file like so,

```
echo $args['key_1']; // foo
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but how do I call the template using the function, I'm still new with wordpress and woocommerce.

`<?php get_template_part( 'path/to/file', 'optional-slug' ); ?>` is it something like this?

Comment: @clestcruz Yes, along those lines. I added some examples to my answer oh how to use the function with action hooks.